# WinForms menu populated with the same programs as the new context menu in Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, registry, ms-office

I am trying to create a menu in WinForms which taps into the registry key "ShellNew" to populate the list of programs that the user can create a new instance of.

Obviously I can find the items with this key but I don't know what to do with them next.

For instance, I get .library-ms. How can I find what office programs they have from this?

The goal is to enable the user to open a new document from programs they have installed, working like the new menu. I may be going about this the completely wrong way.

Comment: I think you'd have to then take the entries and cross-reference them against the keys in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` to figure out what those extensions are to open.

Comment: Thanks I will close this now as you pointed me in the right direction